# Counting rows/records in a multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, dynamic, count

I have a set of nested arrays.

[data] is the top level array.

The lower level arrays are all  identified by incremental numbers, dynamically assigned...essentially each sub-array identifies a row/record of information.

How would I extract the count of the sub-arrays?  I need to be able to do this to post this data into a DB.

The number of sub-arrays is dynamic, and can change depending on what data I am parsing through.

```
 [data] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 3475
                    [name] => Player1
                    [score] => 11870
                    [rank] => 213
                    [total_cities] => 2
                    [crown] => None
                    [alliance_id] => 134
                    [title] => Earl
                    [fame_total] => 509875
                    [fame_rank] => 381
                    [defeated_total] => 3436
                    [defeated_rank] => 376
                    [plunder_total] => 1388754
                    [plunder_rank] => 245
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 3523
                    [name] => Player2
                    [score] => 1978
                    [rank] => 281
                    [total_cities] => 1
                    [crown] => None
                    [alliance_id] => 134
                    [title] => Baron
                    [fame_total] => 0
                    [fame_rank] => 448
                    [defeated_total] => 0
                    [defeated_rank] => 448
                    [plunder_total] => 0
                    [plunder_rank] => 436
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 73
                    [name] => Player3
                    [score] => 1308
                    [rank] => 304
                    [total_cities] => 1
                    [crown] => None
                    [alliance_id] => 134
                    [title] => Marquess
                    [fame_total] => 5604153
                    [fame_rank] => 237
                    [defeated_total] => 37270
                    [defeated_rank] => 229
                    [plunder_total] => 68130
                    [plunder_rank] => 335
                )
```

Comment: I'm not really sure I understand what the question even is, but array_count() with the recursive flag? or simply array_count($myArray['data'])

Comment: `array_count($data)` or `array_count($_POST['data'])` just give me back a no properties flag.  What I am trying to simply do is count the number of sub-arrays in a main array. I have figured out what code works below; my next step is to use that code as the loop in which I will run SQL statements to insert/update a database.

Comment: WHat is a no properties flag?

Comment: When I try to echo the results of `array_count($data)` or `array_count($_POST['data'])` all it shows me in the console is no properties. I have defined `@data=$_POST['data']` in my code so either should work. when i try to assign `$count = array_count($data)` and then do `echo $count`, all I get in browser console is no properties. that's all it says.  of course, that's trying to use the method you highlighted. if you read down I did get my end result, so thanks for responding.

Answer (score 2):

I used a combination of the methods highlighted by Marc B and Thanos to get my desired result

This is the code I used:

```
$count = 0;
foreach($data as $data=>$inner_array){
   $count = $count+1;
}

echo $count;
```

I ran it with a test data set with 143 unique rows, and I got that echo back, so life is good.

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest method:

```
$count = 0;
foreach($mainarray as $subarray)
   $count += count($subarray);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume $data is your main array:
This one prints the name of each inner array (0, 1, 2... for your example) and then counts each sub-array items:

```
echo "Number of sub-arrays: ".count($online_time); //optional
foreach($data as $inner_array=>$data_of_inner_array) {
echo $inner_array;
echo " --- ".count($data_of_inner_array);
echo "<br/>";
}
```

i assume output will be

```
Number of sub-arrays: 3
0 --- 14
1 --- 14
2 --- 14
```

Comment: Thanks, but all I am looking to do is count the sub arrays.  How would I do that?  I don't need to know the element count within the sub array because that is fixed.

Comment: isn't it the first row? the "optional"? which is the expected result at your example?

Comment: expected result was just a straight count and I have achieved it by the method I have written up above. Thank you for getting me pointed in the right direction.